# Migration names should contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores

Tags: django, django-south

I am getting the following error:

> $(test)kr1sek@kr1sek:~/.virtualenvs/test/mysite$ python manage.py datamigration test1 –-initial
>   Migration names should contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores.
>   $(test)kr1sek@kr1sek:~/.virtualenvs/test/mysite$ 
>   `

idk how to fix it..

Answer (score 1):

South's Data migration takes no initial argument, it should be the migration name, e.g:

```
python manage.py datamigration test1 loading_initial_data
```

`initial` is related to schemamigration, for the initial schema of the app.